# How do I get my WordPress dropdown to stop/wrap and shift to the right?

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I am trying to get the drop-down list on my WordPress Salient theme to stop and wrap to the right on certain elements. I've tried some different css things but so far no luck.

I believe the class I need to edit is:

```
.sf-menu a {

display: block;
position: relative;
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
    <li id="menu-item-59258" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-59258"><a href="https://myunion.edu/academics/bachelors/business-management/">Business Management</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-59259" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-59259"><a href="https://myunion.edu/academics/bachelors/child-and-adolescent-development/">Child &amp; Adolescent Development</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-59260" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-59260"><a href="https://myunion.edu/bachelors-degree/criminal-justice-management/">Criminal Justice Management</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-59261" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-59261"><a href="https://myunion.edu/academics/bachelors/early-childhood-studies/">Early Childhood Studies</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-59264" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-59264"><a href="https://myunion.edu/academics/bachelors/elementary-education/">Elementary Education</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-59265" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-59265"><a href="https://myunion.edu/academics/bachelors/emergency-services-management/">Emergency Services Management</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-59266" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-59266"><a href="https://myunion.edu/academics/bachelors/exceptional-student-education/">Exceptional Student Education</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-59267" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-59267"><a href="https://myunion.edu/academics/bachelors/maternal-child-health/">Maternal Child Health: Human Lactation</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-59268" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-59268"><a href="https://myunion.edu/academics/bachelors/organizational-leadership/">Organizational Leadership</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-59269" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-59269"><a href="/academics/bachelors/psychology/">Psychology</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-59270" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-59270"><a href="https://myunion.edu/academics/bachelors/secondary-education/">Secondary Education</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-59271" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-59271"><a href="https://myunion.edu/academics/bachelors/social-work/">Social Work</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understood your question right, add this to your CSS and see if that's what you are after

```
.submenu .submenu{
          -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
          -moz-column-count: 2;
           column-count:2;
          -webkit-column-gap:0;
          -moz-column-gap:0;
           column-gap:0;
           width:32em;
}
```

The [support](http://www.caniuse.com/#search=column) for the `column-*` properties I used above seems to be pretty decent. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: That did exactly what I was after.  Thank you so much!

Comment: That worked perfectly.  However instead of using submenu I had to use sub-menu.  Other than that it worked perfect.. thank you!